# Sql applying a floor to Datetime, Where the floor is not standard e.g. every 2 hours, every 2 day etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, floor

**Aim**: Sql applying a floor to Datetime, Where the floor is not standard e.g. every 2 hours, every 3 day. Instead of the standard every hour, every day etc.

**General purpose**: To enable comparison of data for each collection period. when a collection period it larger then a standard unit of time. While keeping the benefits of Datetime type.

**Example of the conversion:**

floor a datetime to 2 hours

```
+==========================+=======================+
|        WhenCreated       |       Time_Slot       |
+==========================+=======================+
|   2019-02-28 00:34:00    | 2019-02-28 00:00:00   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|   2019-02-28 01:34:00    | 2019-02-28 00:00:00   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|   2019-02-28 02:00:00    | 2019-02-28 02:00:00   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|   2019-02-28 02:20:00    | 2019-02-28 02:00:00   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
|   2019-02-28 03:59:00    | 2019-02-28 02:00:00   |
+--------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**Current Solution:**

inside the select statement will create an new column [Time_Slot] based on [WhenCreated]:

```
left(convert(varchar(30), WhenCreated, 102),4) + '-' + left(right(convert(varchar(30), WhenCreated, 102),5),2) + '-' + right(convert(varchar(30), WhenCreated, 102),2) + ' ' +
    case
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('00','01') then '00:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('02','03') then '02:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('04','05') then '04:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('06','07') then '06:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('08','09') then '08:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('10','11') then '10:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('12','13') then '12:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('14','15') then '14:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('16','17') then '16:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('18','19') then '18:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('20','21') then '20:00:00.000'
        when left(cast(cast(WhenCreated as time) as varchar(30)),2) in ('22','23') then '22:00:00.000'
    end as [Time_Slot]
```

**Current Challenge:**
The current solution works, but it is messy. There has to be a simpler method. So what is a better way to do this?

Edit: fixed error in table.

Comment: This reads like a homework question, and I'm not even sure if that code above is written by you, or your tutor. Also, your sample data doesn't make sense, why does `'01:34:00` round to `'00:00:00'` and `'02:00:00'` to `'02:00:00'`, but `'02:34:00'` to `'01:00:00'`? Have you made any attempts to simplify the above?

Comment: No the code was not written by me. I had been thinking about it for a bit and then went to a colleague to discuss. This was his solution, however we both figured there was probably a better way. No it is not a home work question. I like questions formatted this way as it helps future readers.  Oops. your right, the hours are not right, I forgot to double check after building the table.

Comment: @AaronC We don't need a story, giving us irrelevant information. E.g. the background about PBI has no impact on the question, and makes the question sound smaller in scope, when it actually applies to many other scenarios too.

Comment: @Andreas, I can see your point. I did get a bit carried away. Will shorted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deconstruct the date into its parts, then reconstruct it using the necessary parts, adjusting the part that needs to be floor'd.

To floor an integer value to a multiplier, simply divide by the multiplier and multiply it again. This relies on integer division truncating the division result, e.g. `5 / 2 = 2`, so `5 / 2 * 2 = 4`, i.e. truncated to multiple of 2.

So, to floor the `WhenCreated` value to multiple of 2 hours:

```sql
DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( YEAR(WhenCreated), MONTH(WhenCreated), DAY(WhenCreated),
                    DATEPART(HOUR, WhenCreated) / 2 * 2, /*min*/0, /*sec*/0, /*milli*/0 )
```

Comment: Thanks! tested it, and it worked in tsql. We did look at using DATETIMEFROMPARTS but did not think to use it this way.